# How can I fast-forward a branch without checking it out

Tags: git

On my production server, I just have `master` always checked out.

I do `git pull`, which also updates `develop` branch.

When I commit to `master` on the production server, and try to `git push`, it complains for `develop` that "non-fast-forward updates were rejected".

How can I deal with `master` without ever getting problems related to other branches? I don't even want to know about other branches for this local repo.

Comment: Could you do `git pull master` instead of `git pull`, so you don't even get those other branches? (I'm still pretty inexperienced with Git, so I don't know whether this would work, but it seems plausible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the branch:

```
git push origin master
```

If you don't specify the branch, it goes with what you have in `.git/config`.

So if you always want to only deal with `master` on the production server, update the `.git/config` there removing the other branch associations (so leave the `[branch "master"]` section but remove the `[branch "develop"]` section), and then you can just `git push` again with no arguments.

Comment: Just to note, this worked, but first I had to resolve the non-fastfoward error with `git checkout develop` and `git merge origin/develop` then `git checkout master` before this worked. This makes sense, but just for anyone who later finds this information.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the git push, specify the branch, i.e.

```
git push origin master
```